# How do cross derivatives work?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm having trouble understanding why in the cross derivatives $\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial y} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ we first treat $x$ as a constant while differentiating with respect to $y$ and then differentiating with respect to $x$ the resulting expression. Aren't we losing information about the inputs by treating them as constants?.

Comment: Maybe you can try out a few examples to see if you are losing information.

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify what "treat $x$ as a constant" means:$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,\,b):=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f(a,\,b+k)-f(a,\,b)}{k}.$$Hence the definition$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,\,b):=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f(a+h,\,b+k)-f(a+h,\,b)}{k}-\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f(a,\,b+k)-f(a,\,b)}{k}}{h}$$has no inconsistency or information loss regarding how any variable is used. The hard part is proving [something useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) about such second-order derivatives.